# cant see bitcoin after restore of backup

Tags: bitcoin-core

I made a backup of my Qt wallet. The blockchain never got completely downloaded and i was sent a bitcoin that i never saw in my wallet as the downloading of the blockchain never caught up with the transaction. I placed this backup file into another Qt wallet that was fully up to date with the blockchain, thinking that i would see the bitcoin but I only see my bitcoin address. 
Can anyone please tell me how this is?

Answer (score 2):

Try running bitcoin-qt with the -rescan argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please can you tell me how i run bitcoin-qt-rescan?

Comment: Go to the folder: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin** hold shift and right-click and select "open command window here" ( [pic](http://i.imgur.com/nXe5tSn.jpg) ). Now type: **bitcoin-qt.exe -rescan** and press the Enter key  ( [pic](http://i.imgur.com/KNBgzTS.jpg) ). You can close the cmd window afterwards.

Comment: @bob: Or you can just go to "properties" for the link you use to run Bitcoin, and add -rescan to the command.

Comment: thanks for the comments. still cant do it though. i tried Nicolai's advice but i have a different configuration. i have daemon. src. bitcoin-qt. COPYING. readme. uninstall. when i right click over bitcoin-qt i have a different popup box without the option to go to rescan. i have tried your advice meni but dont see how i can add - rescan to the command. would you mind giving me detailed instructions as to how to do this. thanks a lot

Comment: @bob, do you have a Bitcoin shortcut on your Start menu? You can (temporarily) edit the properties of that to include the -rescan option.