# Block data error, reindexing blocks

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, windows

Bitcoin QT finished syncing this weekend after d/l for Windows 7 on Thursday.

Today, probably 2nd or 3rd time running it, an error came up right away that index could not be found.

What would cause this to happen, and why would it have to reindex all the blocks on disk?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Did you recently do a non-clean shutdown? (Crash, power loss, etc)

Comment: Running a rescan might help: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7734/516

Comment: -rescan checks for missing wallet transactions. The error here is because a database sanity check at startup fails, where the wallet isn't even touched yet.

Answer (score 2):

When I've had this happen it's been because of a non-clean shutdown. Something about the disk state ends up being inconsistent and this (understandably) results in the system wanting to verify all the information it has on disk.