# How to Create Wallet using Bitcoind

Tags: wallet

How can i create a wallet for web based application for bitcoin i.e., unique address for each user along with the private key?

Does using bitcoind help me with this and how can i do this ?

I want to create wallet for each user who access a site. How can i do this?

Bitcoind getnewaddress '' command works and produces a new address but where is the private key for this address.

Comment: please see if my answer to this question also solves your problem: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11977/bitcoin-qt-multiple-wallets-and-transferring-between/19940#19940

Answer (score 2):

The getnewaddress command will create a new private key/address and associate this with the default account, which is "" (has no name).

You can assign private keys to different accounts by naming them, and if you used:

```
bitcoind getnewaddress "account1"
```

This would create a new private key/address for the account "account1". This doesn't create multiple wallet.dat files, just different accounts.

You could store all the keys in the bitcoin core wallet and have each web users "wallet" be created as a different account in bitcoin core.