# Is one Bitcoin node has One wallet only?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I have configured Bitcoin core testnet on my VPS and by running bitcoin-cli command "**bitcoin-cli -testnet getwalletinfo**" its show wallet info and it create all new bitcoin testnet address under this.

Is there any bitcoin-cli command to create new wallet on same node ?

Answer (score 1):

As of v 0.14.x, Bitcoin Core supports only one wallet.  You can't create more than one.

You can sort of achieve this by having multiple wallet files and choosing which one you rename to `wallet.dat`.  You have to restart Bitcoin Core to change between them.  It's error-prone and not an officially supported feature.  You can read more about it at [Bitcoin-qt multiple wallets and transferring between?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11977/bitcoin-qt-multiple-wallets-and-transferring-between)

Comment: Bitcoin Core 0.15 will support multiple wallets.