# Restore wallet.dat on windows 8

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, backup, wallet.dat

How do I use my `wallet.dat` on my windows 8 bitcoin qt?

Someone posted this

`C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (XP)`

`C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista and 7)`

but I'm on windows 8, so i don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 is just like Windows 7.

But on a mondern bitcoin-core installation you will be asked where to put your data-directory. So if you changed the default path you need to consider that.

So if you found your data directory, your wallet.dat file is right there. Make a backup or restore it as you wish.

There is also a good tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9gQmmC5mzY) around for more visual explanation.

For a more detailed explanation on what steps are required to restoring your wallet.dat you can check out [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10975/17113).

Comment: Can't you just search for `wallet.dat`?