# Import two wallet.dat into Bitcoin-Qt client

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup, wallet-import

This is very closely related to [Import wallet.dat into a new Bitcoin-Qt client](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/import-wallet-dat-into-a-new-bitcoin-qt-client), but I feel this is not a duplicate because the (great) answer to that Q is for only restoring one wallet.

I used Bitcoin-QT about a year back and had two separate wallets within it.  I have these backed up as two separate wallet.dat files.  After some computer wipe, I now need to restore the two wallets into the one Bitcoin-QT client.

Using the prior Q, I have been able to import one of the wallets back into the Bitcoin-Qt client.  I now need to bring the other one in.

How can I import a second backup into my existing account, without the need of sending my first wallets amount to a separate external wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (yet) no multi wallet support in bitcoin-core.

You can try to stop Bitcoin-Qt, replace your wallet.dat (rename the old one, place the new one) and start Bitcoin-Qt. If your wallet is really old, it will perform a rescan for new transactions and this can take some minutes.

To merge your wallets:

- Open Console and enter `dumpwallet <filename>`
- Stop Bitcoin-Qt
- Replace wallet.dat with your new wallet file (move the current wallet.dat file to a save place)
- Start Bitcoin-Qt
- Open Console and enter `importwallet <filename>`.

Comment: hey Jonas, does merging work between an HD wallet (v0.13.1) and a non-HD one(0.12.1)?