# Can I retrieve my bitcoins from years ago that I never received?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, wallet.dat, lost-bitcoins

How can I get hold of my bitcoins that never made it to my wallet years ago?

I purchased some bitcoins years ago (have got my receipt and all emails from who I purchased). I downloaded `Bitcoin-Qt 7`, synced it, got an address for the seller. It went through, but I could never sync it again as I was using prepaid internet credit. So, the bitcoins never got to my wallet! I gave up for a few years, but now I have unlimited download. Now `Bitcoin-Qt 7` has a download issue. I switched to `Bitcoin Core 11` now. I would like to know how I can get hold of my bitcoins?

Ther was no data transferred over to Bitcoin Core 11 sadly. Please can any one help me?

Comment: I purchased them through spendbitcoins and they state that if I haven't received them to contact my wallet provider but I can not find a way to contact my wallet provider (bitcoin qt). Does any one know how or more to say who I contact to prove my proof of purchase and my coins sent to my bitcoin core wallet???

Answer (score 8):

If you still have the `wallet.dat` file and your password you can access your bitcoins. You do not have to use `Bitcoin-Qt 7` and it does not matter if your wallet ever synced before. If the sender sent the bitcoins to an address you control and the transaction was confirmed, the bitcoin are yours.

https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet

If you want to use a new version of `Bitcoin-Qt` you can do that too: See [Import wallet.dat into a new Bitcoin-Qt client](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/import-wallet-dat-into-a-new-bitcoin-qt-client)

Comment: Well I have looked all through my bitcoin qt 7 file and there is no wallet.dat file. For some reason there is nothing on my back ups on my hard drive. My wallet never synced for it to reach my wallet. what are my options now? I have block chain info and where it is. I have the address from my bitcoin qt wallet where it was ment to go but never did! So should i try and drag my bitcoin qt wallet to block chain and see if it works! I would think it wouldnt since wallet.dat is strangely not there!   @animal instinct

Comment: Is it possible that it all transferred over to my bitcoin core 11 when I downloaded the wallet? Some other bloke said that would happen! But i havent seen my bitcoins or the address they were sent to in my bitcoincore wallet!   @animal instinct

Comment: Go to the debug console in 0.11 and type `validateaddress address` (filling in your actual address). It will report `ismine : true` if that address is in your wallet.

Comment: @kym: Is your Bitcoin Core 11 fully synchronized now?