# Recovering wallet after update to Btc core 0.13

Tags: wallet

I updated my bitcoin core to 0.13 version and my wallet is empty and my transactions doesnt show anymore either. I've re scan .dat to make sure. How can I recover it ?

Comment: Did you install to a different directory? Do you have a backup of the `wallet.dat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/import-wallet-dat-into-a-new-bitcoin-qt-client