# How long for Bitcoin core to initially synchronise?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Now i tried sweeping with my private key but its says needed to confirm output no output

Answer (score 1):

> **how long will [Bitcoin core] take to sync?**

How long it takes to sync depends on your computer and your network connection.

It may take a week.

Bitcoin core will give you an estimate - but that assumes the computer is never turned off, never sleeps, hibernates or drops into a low-power mode and never runs other CPU-intensive tasks while core is syncing.

> **is there a way to get the bitcoin out incase**

in case of what?

You can export the private key and then import it into a lightweight (SPV) wallet which will allow you to spend your BTC without needing to download and verify the whole blockchain first.

See

- https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/78758/13866 which covers debug console commands

  ```
  listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
  dumpprivkey <address>
  ```
- [How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4203/13866)
- [List of wallets showing which support SPV](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_wallets_list)

Comment: I tried sweeping now with my private key but its says needed to confirm output whats dies it mean pleas

Comment: @Olamilekan: You are new here but the main purpose of this website is to create a set of questions and answers that other people with the same problems will also find useful. By editing your original question and changing it completely you have undermined this. If you have a follow-on question, please use the "Ask Question" button above to ask a new question. You can put a link to this question in the new question if you feel it is relevant. You can "roll back" an edit if you change your mind (use "roll back" link in the [edit history](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/79074/revisions))

Comment: I dont know how to use it am sorry Okay i will but please before that let me explain better  my bitcoincore is syn and i have my bitcoin in it so from the videos i watched on youtube i went took the reciving address and paste in debuorg and i got a private key and i firstly i paste the private key on a sweep website and the new address i want to send it too and it saying no utxo for this addres and i also tried it on electrum is says no output needed to confirm the output thays what prompt my question is there anything i need to do thanks

Comment: If you pasted your private key into a website you have given your bitcoins to the people who run that website. It isn't clear what exactly you have done. I suggest you start a new question and paste in all the addresses you used. Do not paste your private key anywhere. Explain exactly which websites you used. Post screenshots of messages you want help with.

Comment: I dont really know how to use this app to put the screenshot but the site it (sweepkey.org) but i tried to check the address i sent my coin to on blockchain it shows it has only 1 transaction and theres balance there what do you think

Comment: Sweepkey.org is the name of the site and i tried to get the address i sent my coin to in my bitcoin core and i checked it on blockchain it has only 1 transaction and it still has the same balance i sent is there any chance i wont meet my money when my bitcoin core finish syn