# I know I had Bitcoins back in the Day, but

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I have all my old computers and have the hard drives, so how do I systematically go back finding which on has my bitcoins?  At the time, I figured it was no big deal, but now finding the correct one, could be worth while.

So my question is, how to I search my hard drives to find the one that contains the bitcoins?   Is there a file I need to search for?

Comment: What year would you have received the coins? There are many ways to store bitcoins (private keys). A timeline would be useful in answering your question.

Comment: It would of been in the 2005-2011 time frame.  I thought it was a waste of my time, but back then, I was into everything that promised money...  I found 2011 emails on my current account saying they were a waste of time, so back in 2011, I thought they were junk...

Comment: My emails even suggest I would give them away, as I didn't really care, if anyone wanted them, but that email chain runs dry, which means I have some, somewhere....

Comment: So they had to me obtained in 2011 or before, so I'm assuming they might me worth something,  The question, is can I search the hard drives for a certain file?

Comment: Take a look at the question I just marked this as duplicate of. Most wallets use a 'wallet.dat' file, but there are many ways to store bitcoins using local software (eg bitcoin-core or electrum), physical mediums (paper wallets), third party services (eg blockchain.info), etc. Its probably best to approach your treasure hunt with a wide scope. Best of luck!

Comment: I can't imagine I spent more than $100 at the time and knowing me probably only $50, but if I can reclaim, it would be nice

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version you were running, and the operating system, and when you say you are looking for your bitcoins, what you are really looking for are the private keys.

### Bitcoin Core

The keys are in a file called `wallet.dat` which was stored in the bitcoin core data directory, which I'll call `<data-dir>`. The `wallet.dat` file was stored in `<data-dir>/` on versions prior to `v0.16.0` and moved to `<data-dir>/wallets` in later versions, see [files.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/files.md). This uses the [`bitkeys` format](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4448.0).

**Linux**
On linux, the data directory `<data-dir>` is `~/.bitcoin/wallets/wallet.dat`

**Windows**
On Windows, the data directory `<data-dir>` is `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\wallet.dat`

**Mac**
On Mac, the data directory `<data-dir>` is `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`

Reference: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#Mac

---

The next question is "How do I restore the keys?", and there are many answers for that already, example: [Import wallet.dat into a new Bitcoin-Qt client](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10974/60443)

Comment: Note: there are many ways to store private keys, this answer assumes you were running the bitcoin-core full node software and wallet. Searching for ‘wallet.dat’ is nonetheless a good starting point in almost any case I’m sure.

Comment: Ok, the question next, is when I find Wallet.dat, then how do I take that to cash in?

Comment: @MarkJaske That's a different question (i.e. probably not suitable for the comments section). You need to select a wallet, import your keys, and then sell them either in person or on an exchange.