# recovery of old wallet.dat file

Tags: wallet.dat

Back in 2012, I mined for a bit on my computer in Slush pool.  I didn't get much, like .11 coins so I quit.
In 2018 I went to slush pool and sent my sats to my bitcoin core wallet then tried to open it, but my hard drive was too small to download the blockchain and it errored out, so I let it sit.  in late 2021, I saved the wallet.dat file, downloaded the new Bitcoin_qt and the entire blockchain on a new 64 bit machine, with a large drive, and tried to drop the wallet.dat file into the folder to replace the blank one.  Bitcoin core doesn't see it so now I am at a loss.  I am not a command line guy nor do I know how to proceed.... should I chalk the sats up as lost and move on?

Comment: If you've put it in the wallets folder of your data directory, can you see it when you choose file > open wallet? You'll have to start a rescan if you've loaded the wallet but let's first ensure it can be loaded before going into those details.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `File -> Open Wallet` option to select your wallet and load it into BitcoinCore. Alternatively the `loadwallet "filename" ( load_on_startup )` command may be what you are looking for should the GUI option not work. [This post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/import-wallet-dat-into-a-new-bitcoin-qt-client) shows how you need to locate the wallet so that BitcoinCore will find it. Rescanning may be needed, but if your file is not corrupted it should recognize the funds.

Alternatively, you may use Electrum, since you mentioned downloading the whole chain is an issue for you.

In case you do not remember your password, or just its approximate shape/length there is software available to brute-force some combinations yourself. Whatever you do, do not share the file with anyone promising to help you.

All the best recovering your funds.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: As far as Electrum... how would I open the wallet there?  can it open the wallet.dat file?

Comment: Electrum does have an option to open wallets under File->Open->(select your wallet). However, I use BitcoinCore for all wallet-y stuff, so my knowledge there is limited.

Comment: Thx David.  I guess I probably lost the piece of coin... like a lot of people over the years.